# BOT:Converting comment to CW

Tags: discussion, comments, robots

I stumbled upon this line in [a post on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/648734/189304):

> BOT:Converting comment to CW...

Is there an automatic conversion of popular comments to community wiki posts I'm not aware of? How does it work then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an automatic conversion of popular comments to community wiki posts I'm not aware of?

No, there is no such thing.

> How does it works then?

Guess the OP started writing a comment, then decided to expand it into an answer. No idea why they'd want to add that to the top of their post.

Comment: Weird of him. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 4):

Someone decided to post several "community wiki" answers to unanswered questions that were resolved in comments. [Searching for "bot convert comments"](https://serverfault.com/search?q=BOT+Convert+comments) brings up <s>11 such posts</s> nothing, now that the posts were edited.

A commendable effort, be it CW or not, although the cryptic remark on top is unnecessary and, as we see here, distracting.